# Return a value from a for each?

Tags: javascript

Looping through an object using either `Object.keys(arr).forEach((item) {` or lodash `_.forEach(arr, (item, key) => {`.

How can I return a value from inside the loop.

```
let myTestValue = _.forEach(arr, (item, key) => {
    return item.id ? true : false;
});
```

Basically I want to test for `item.id` in a loop, as long as all items `return true`, it's ok, as soon as any `return false`, I want to break out of the loop. In reality the test is a little more complex but the above is just a basic example.

`myTestValue` only needs to hold either `true` or `false`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191450/discussion-on-question-by-panthro-return-a-value-from-a-for-each).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and exit the loop with the first false value.

```js
var object = { one: { id: 'a' }, two: {}, three: { id: 'c' } },
    hasAllId = Object.values(object).every(item => item.id);

console.log(hasAllId);
```

Comment: @panthro *how*? this does exactly what you described in your question. How would it not work?

Comment: Could you show me a working example with an object?

Comment: please add your object. and the comparison part.

Comment: where do you get the property `id` from?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
function isBelowThreshold(currentValue) {
  /**
   * Here, we can log which elements are being checked.
   * In the log, you will see that 1 is checked, then 30 is checked,
   * then none of the rest of the elements are checked
   * since 30 fails the threshold.
  */
  console.log(currentValue);
  return currentValue < 30;
}

var array1 = [1, 30, 39, 29, 10, 13];

// This outputs false because not all the elements are below 30:
console.log(array1.every(isBelowThreshold));
```